# Spring boot webflux TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm using spring-boot with the dependency spring-boot-starter-webflux,
    i want to get one data per second with browser,
    when i use spring-boot version 2.1.4,the code is working,
    but 2.1.5 or greater version not working, 
    i will get all of the data at 10 sesonds later,not one data per second

```
I want to get the reason,or others i should  do 


I find spring-boot update the dependency of netty in 2.1.5,
so if i add the dependency in my pom.xml with 
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.8.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

it working


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class DemoController {
    // just get a string per second
    @GetMapping(value = "",produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String>  getMsg(){
       return Flux.fromStream(new Random().ints(10).mapToObj(intStream -> 
       {
           try {
               TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return "this is data "+intStream;
       }));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can play around with `delayElements` operator of Flux. That's better fit for reactive since that is not blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will achieve what it is you are going for.

```
@GetMapping(value = "",produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> getMsg(){
    return Flux.fromStream(new Random()
            .ints(10)
            .mapToObj(value -> "this is data " + value))
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
}
```

Comment: thanks,I set the delay time to 0. I get one data ai one time ,not all datas  at the last.

Comment: I am still confused over this and not sure what I am doing wrong. My situation is similar, data is coming all at once but not at 1 sec interval.   Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908428/server-sent-event-eventstream-is-empty-and-only-shows-in-network-tab-when-flux-m